# Broadcast receiver for notifications

Tags: android

I am currently developing a simple sms alarm which plays an alarm whenever a certain number is texting you or when a certain word is showing up in the message.
   Now i want to do the same thing, but with notifications.
   I want my app to alert me when certain word appears in the notification title or text.
My question is, it is possible to catch all the notifications in a broadcast receiver like i do with the sms?

Comment: you mean to say, you want to add a filter at the notification tray level? So instead of sms, it could be any application or service triggering the notification Message...?  Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way, that would not read everything in the notification would be to set up your application as Accessability application that's allowed to listen to (pretty much) everything.

But in 4.3 they have added the [NotificationListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html). Best guideance is probably to look at the docs. There's an another example available: https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example

Comment: What about a pre-api level 18? Can a notification be caught in a broadcast receiver maybe ?

Comment: @DoruAdryan Yes, but that is in a bad way. Disguising the app as an accessability (for instance blind people) that can read some of the text of a notification. If you have several mails incoming you will only see X emails to email@example.com